# Delphi/Indy. Long delay in procedure TIdStackWindows.Connect

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, delphi-2006, indy10, connection-timeout

My app is hanging in the call to procedure `TIdStackWindows.Connect`.  When the TCP/IP address exists there is no problem, but if it doesn't, I get the hang.  The IP address is a literal- there is no DNS lookup involved.  I was expecting the connection attempt to fail after the timeout (`TCPClient.ConnectTimeout`) I have set of 1 second but the app hangs for up to 30 seconds on this call (the call from my app isn't threaded.  I intend to move the TCP connection to a thread, but the long connect timeout will still be an issue).

If I pause execution in the Delphi IDE when the app is unresponsive, I an positioned at:

```
ntdll.KiUserApcDispatcher:
7C90E450 8D7C2410         lea edi,[esp+$10]
```

I then F8 a couple of times until I see a stack frame. I am then at:

```
IdStack.TIdStack.RaiseSocketError(10038)
IdStack.TIdStack.RaiseLastSocketError
IdStack.TIdStack.CheckForSocketError(-1)
IdStackWindows.TIdStackWindows.Connect(912,'10.8.2.170',5001,Id_IPv4)
IdSocketHandle.TIdSocketHandle.Connect
IdIOHandlerStack.TIdConnectThread.Execute
:00451fc1 HookedTThreadExecute + $2D
Classes.ThreadProc($254B910)
System.ThreadWrapper($5456CB0)
:00451ea3 CallThreadProcSafe + $F
:00451f10 ThreadExceptFrame + $3C
:7c80b729 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
```

I note after a bit of poking around that this topic has received a bit of traffic.  The common answer seems to be "put it in a thread".  I intend to, but the long timeout will still be problematic.  Why does the connect timeout not work?  I'm using Indy 10.5.5 and Delphi 2006 - if I upgrade to the latest build of Indy will there be much migration involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking sockets have no concept of a connect timeout at the API layer, so Indy's `ConnectTimeout` is a manually implemented timeout. Indy calls `TIdStack.Connect()` in an internal worker thread while `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` runs a sleep loop that waits for that thread to terminate. If the loop detects the `ConnectTimeout` period has elapsed, it closes the socket, which is supposed to cause the blocked `TIdStack.Connect()` to exit immediately, but that is not a guarantee. There is OS overhead in creating and terminating a thread as well. It should definitely not take 30 seconds to react to a 1 second timeout, but on the other hand 1 second is usually too small. It is possible that the thread will not even begin running within 1 second. You should typically set the `ConnectTimeout` to 5-10 seconds at a minimum to give the OS enough time to do its work.

Comment: Thanks, Remy.  I'm suspicious because I've seen other comments on this problem that mention 30 seconds (the delay is within 10mS of 30 seconds as well - so there's probably a piece of source code somewhere with a hard-coded 30000 mS delay).  I'll try a longer delay tomorrow but I'm not hopeful.

Comment: There is no hard-coded 30 second delay in Indy's code (there is a hard-coded 2 minute timeout if `ConnectTimeout` is 0, though). See the implementation of `TIdIOHandlerStack.ConnectClient()` in IdIOHandlerStack.pas. The sleep loop that runs while `connect()` is busy does use 125 ms (max) sleeps per loop iteration, but that would take a lot of delay on the API's part to add up to 30 seconds. Note that if you call `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` inside the main thread and you are using the `TIdAntiFreeze` component, then additional delays can be caused by the VCL's main message queue outside of Indy.

Comment: I was thinking of Windows, rather than Indy, when it came to the 30000 mS delay! :)